# Marking up citations in HTML

Tags: xhtml, quotes, semantic-markup, web-standards, rdfa

Is there a somewhat standardized way to semantically mark up citations in HTML? I know that when I'm citing from a website i can do:

```
<q title="Article by John" cite="http://example.com/article">quoted text...</q>
```

But I was rather thinking something a bit more precise, maybe using [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa) and [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/). Along the lines of:

```
<q cite="http://example.com/article">quoted text...</q>
<span xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" about="#berkman">
    <cite property="dc:title">Find It Fast: How to Uncover Expert Information on Any Subject</cite>
    <span property="dc:creator">Berkman, R. I.</span>
    <span property="dc:date">1994</span>
    <span property="dc:publisher">New York: HarperPerennial</span>
    <span property="dc:type">book</span>
</span>
```

Then I could run some Javascript or XSLT over it to display the citation as a hover-text or footnote or something ([HTML5 recommendation on footnotes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#footnotes)). But this way seems to be rather loose on semantics. Isn't there a smart way to associate the quoted text (in the q tag) with an RDF triple? Like:

```
"quoted text..." voc:isQuotedFrom _b1.
_b1 dc:title "Find it Fast";
    dc:creator "Berkman, R. I.".
```

I've stubled over [BibTeXML](http://bibtexml.sourceforge.net/examples.html) and [a proposed Citation microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/citation) but they (as well as all usages of Dublin Core I've seen) always seem to focus on the metadata of a specific book (as it might appear in a bibliography) and not on how to mark up a citation and reference it to a book.

Any thoughts or tips appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the BIBO Ontology - it has all the terms you want:

http://bibotools.googlecode.com/svn/bibo-ontology/trunk/doc/index.html

In particular:

```
bibo:citedBy
bibo:cites
bibo:Quote
```

RDF doesn't support literals as subjects.

So in the example above I would recommend the following, based on the new RDFa-Core Specification:

```
<div vocab="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/" typeof="Quote">
    <span rel="cites" resource="http://mybookstore.com/books#berkman"></span>
    <q cite="http://example.com/article" property="shortDescription">quoted text...</q>
</div>

<span about="http://mybookstore.com/books#berkman" typeof="Book" prefix="dc: http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" vocab="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/">
    <cite property="dc:title">Find It Fast: How to Uncover Expert Information on Any Subject</cite>
    <span property="dc:creator">Berkman, R. I.</span>
    <span property="dc:date">1994</span>
    <span property="dc:publisher">New York: HarperPerennial</span>
</span>
```

This would resolve to the following rdf:

```
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/> .
@prefix mybooks: <http://mybookstore.com/books#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

_:b1 rdf:type bibo:Quote;
     bibo:cites mybooks:berkman;
     bibo:shortDescription "quoted text...".

mybooks:berkman rdf:type bibo:Book;
        dc:title "Find It Fast: How to Uncover Expert Information on Any Subject";
        dc:creator "Berkman, R. I.";
        dc:date "1994";
        dc:publisher "New York: HarperPerennial".
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. seems a bit verbose (requiring a div, a span and a q tag in the text) but I guess it's the only way :)

Answer (score 0):

Some of it is stored in meta-tags in the header.

`<meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes" />`

and

`<meta name="revised" content="Hege Refsnes, 23/10/2011" />`

both are copy/paste from w3cschools on page on [meta tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)
There are other commonly used ones that are not in the w3c specification. I'm not sure if there is a list anywhere.

additionally if you decide to use html5 there are new tags and attributes for that. some of the tags are [address](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_address.asp), [cite](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_cite.asp), [details](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_details.asp), [summary](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_summary.asp)

Another feature of html5 that you can use in xhtml (although it wont validate in xhtml) is using custom attributes. In html5 you should start them with data-yourAttributName just in case yourAttributeName gets used in later versions of html.

E.G. `<p data-date='13MAR2012'></p>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. unfortunately none of the solutions quite fit my needs; meta is for the whole document, cite is as of html5 for titles only (no author name), details and summary [should not be used for footnoes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-details-element). but there i discovered a nice link to the html5 [recommendation on footnotes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#footnotes) (updated in question). But yeah, maybe I'll end up with custom data-attributes.. btw: [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/) ;)